# Are datum and geodetic datum the same?

Tags: datum

Although I really read many post and text book, I really don't know 'datum' and 'geodetic datum'. If they are different, could you tell me how?

Comment: A *geodetic* datum is just a *specific* datum, defining the geometric references for celestial bodies over auxilliary ellipsoids.